# Produce a matrix using INDEX and MATCH functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three columns: A, B and C.  I'm trying to produce a matrix in cells E, F, G, H and I by using INDEX and MATCH.

```
      [A]   [B]         [C]         [D]   [E]   [F]   [G]   [H]   [I] 
[1]   id    answer     key                       1     2     3     4
[2]   1     yes         1            1     yes   1     0     0     0 
[3]   2     no          2            2     yes   0     0     1     0
[4]   2     yes         3            2      no   0     1     0     1
[5]   2     no          4
```

I already have the column headers, so everything in cells D and F-I.  My formula for cell F2:

```
{=INDEX($A$2:$C$5, MATCH(1, ($A$2:$B$5=$D2:$E2)*($C$2:$C$5=F$1), 0), 1,0)}
```

But I'm getting a `#VALUE!` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in F2 and drag across and down as suited.

Please note, that it is an Array formula, so enter with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`.

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH($D2&$E2&F$1,$A:$A&$B:$B&$C:$C,0))),0,1)
```

Comment: Maybe against the original sample data layout as `=--ISNUMBER(MATCH($D2&$E2&F$1,$A$2:$A$9999&$B$2:$B$9999&$C$2:$C$9999,0))` in F2.

Comment: @jeeped Edited, so it works for the original layout. Whats the purpose of the `--` after the =?

Comment: The [ISNUMBER function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/is-functions-490afee4-fd91-4839-89d4-1257a21b4e25) returns TRUE or FALSE. The *double unary* turns this into 1 or 0.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know this. Will definitely come in handy in the future!

Comment: Yeah, the ranges probably don't have to be almost 10,000 rows tall either but the OP has given no indication of the actual data size and even 10,000 rows is only ¹⁄₁₀₀ of full column references.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to a two-column match, you also have to accommodate picking up a second match. A solution to these two problems combine can be achieved with the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) helping an [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) return the value from C2:C5 to compare to G1:J1 (I shifted my answer key over to the right by a column for readability).

[image: Answer_Key]

The standard formula in my G2 is,

```
=--(G$1=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$5, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$4)/(($A$2:$A$5=$E2)*($B$2:$B$5=$F2)), COUNTIF($F2:F2,  ">"&0)+1)), 0))
```

Fill both right and down. The second **2 | No** answer in J4 is returned correctly.

Comment: nice answer, I was wondering, if you tried my answer? My Excel is running somewhat slow when I try to use it on to many columns. What could be the cause of that?

Comment: @MarcoGetrost - I did and it was picking up the second **2 | No** but the full-column references were impeding quick returns on the calculation cycles. After playing around a bit, I found it could be boiled down to `=--ISNUMBER(MATCH($K2&$L2&M$1,$G:$G&$H:$H&$I:$I,0))` in M2 as a CSE and that helped but those full-column references could really be chopped down a bit. Some mention should have been given that you had shifted the sample data to the right so radically.

Comment: @Jeeped thanks for your help.  I'm following exactly your layout, my the answers all seem to be 0?

Comment: Remember that I shifted your sample data one column right. In the original layout, put my formula into G2 (under the **2**) then select F2 and Delete, Shift Cells Left to get the formula to F2 and fill both right and down. All of the cell references should correct themselves.

Comment: @jeeped but then I'm losing data from F2? :S

Comment: OK, maybe that wasn't a good explanation or recommendation. Try to rearrange your sample data as per my image and use the formula in G2 as suggested. If need be, you can delete the blank column D afterward.